# Is there no HTTPS in Flash Builder?

Tags: https, flash-builder

I have been working on a project for a while now... in Flash Builder. It's now complete; only to find that I can not secure the services. I can't seem to be able to make a https connection...

Is it true? There is no https service provider? It would seem a lot of work down the drain... I could not conceive that there would not be an https connection available.. I have been testing with http so far.

If there is no https I find it unbelievable... such a large framework and no security...

Does anyone know something related to the topic?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that describes a problem or issue. Simply repeating the information that is already in the tags is meaningless. Your title should convey enough meaning to be useful to a future user here who is scanning it in a list of search results.

Comment: Sure you can also use https to connect. Like Ken said it would help if you would exactly describe your problem, sounds like some security issue

Comment: How??? I am using http data services... if I change the url to https (`https://localhost/services/something.php`) I get an error...  `Unable to connect to the URL specified`.... I can not make it any clearer than this... have you been able to make a https data service??? I am using Flash Builder 4.6

Comment: Holy smokes!!! IT worked!!!! Just changed the method of creating the service....  used the old `<mx:HTTPService>` tag and imported the root certificate.... thank God... I was almost certain that all my work had gone down the drain. I must say I am really surprised... It doesn't work with the most common method that one would use on a daily basis....